# JUnit 5 Gradle: Do test classes really have to be suffixed with "Test(s)"?

Tags: gradle, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

It appears as if JUnit 5 tests aren't found if the file- and class name does not end with "Test" or "Tests" when using Gradle. Is it possible to configure Gradle to treat everything in the `test` directory as test classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this doc](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle), note that there is a plugin called 'junit-platform-gradle-plugin'. The salient part is the following:

```groovy
junitPlatform {
    filters {
        includeClassNamePattern '.*'
    }
}
```

(as opposed to `'.*TestCase'`)

Here is the full `build.gradle` file (and [an example](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_47635778) that runs tests named `ExampleTestCase` and `Example2`):

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

ext.junitJupiterVersion  = '5.0.2'

dependencies {
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitJupiterVersion}")
}

junitPlatform {
    filters {
        includeClassNamePattern '.*'
    }
}
```

Comment: Was not working on my machine until I updated regex pattern to `^.*`
At same time it was working for my colleagues. With `^.*` works for everyone